# Flurl POST json throws a 400 (expected) but I do not see the content message

Tags: c#, rest, flurl

Trying to POST a json using Flurl and it comes back with 400 which is expected but the content is lost. When I try  the same request using HttpClient and I do a ReadStringAsync on the content I could see the validation error message thrown by the external API

```
var response = await Policy.Handle<FlurlHttpException>()
                .WaitAndRetryAsync(new[] { TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30) }).ExecuteAsync(() =>
                    $"{_baseEndPoint}{resourceEndPoint}".WithOAuthBearerToken(bearerToken)
                        .WithHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")                        
                        .PostStringAsync(bodyText, cancellationToken).ReceiveJson<T>());
```

This is with HttpClient where I see the validation error message

```
using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var content = new StringContent(bodyText, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", bearerToken);           
            var result =
                await httpClient.PostAsync($"{_baseEndPoint}{resourceEndPoint}", content, cancellationToken);
            var resultString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(cancellationToken);
```

This the object it should deserialize to,

```
public class Parties
{
    [JsonProperty("0")] public List<string> Messages{ get; set; }
}

public class Warning
{
    [JsonProperty("notifcation_error")] public string NotificationError { get; set; }

    public int Party{ get; set; }
}

    public class ResponseForCreate
    {
        [JsonProperty("parties")] public Parties Parties{ get; set; }
    
        [JsonProperty("domain_id")] public List<string> DomainId { get; set; }
    
        [JsonProperty("direction")] public List<string> Direction { get; set; }
    
        [JsonProperty("quote_basis")] public List<string> Basis{ get; set; }
    
        [JsonProperty("non_field_errors")] public List<string> NonFieldErrors { get; set; }
    
        [JsonProperty("warnings")] public List<Warning> Warnings { get; set; }
    
        public string Info { get; set; }
    }
```

Is it possible to see the validation message using Flurl. Thanks

Comment: It seems that you are using Polly with flurl, but not with HttpClient. Any reason for that? Try using Polly with HttpClient and see if you get the same problem. Then it might be flurl being the problem,  but actually Polly.

Comment: Try showing what object type gets returned, and show us the content of the object.

Comment: I removed the Polly bit from the code and I was still not able to receive the validation errors. It was just 400

Comment: I have edited and you can now see the classes which the response should deserialize it to. All works with plain vanilla HttpClient

Answer (score 0):

You are post'ing text but use header "application/json".

You to either edit to PostJsonAsync and post a json object(as i suspect you need to do, as it is what you are doing with HttpClient) or edit to "text/plain" relative to what your API would be expecting.

I dont know what error message you are expecting, but i suspect that you are not getting the correct error message back, because you are not doing what the API expects.

Comment: I tried using PostJsonAsync but fails and goes to to the catch block with 400,  var response = await Policy.Handle<FlurlHttpException>()
                .WaitAndRetryAsync(new[] { TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30) }).ExecuteAsync(() =>
                    $"{_baseEndPoint}{resourceEndPoint}".WithOAuthBearerToken(bearerToken)
                        .WithHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                        .PostJsonAsync(bodyText, cancellationToken).ReceiveJson<T>());

Comment: @Auroops is bodyText a json object or text? You need to post a json object.

Comment: var bodyText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request.Deall);